# Show message when close program in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt

Qt - c++
Show message when user close program
Thanks

Comment: You need to know how to write in English to get answers in StackOveflow

Comment: Atleast your question can be bit descriptive..

Answer (score 2):

Most general is to connect the [aboutToQuit](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal to a slot -- but as the docs say

> The signal is particularly useful if
>   your application has to do some
>   last-second cleanup. Note that no user
>   interaction is possible in this state.

so if you need to show your message *in Qt* (so the main event loop must still be running) this won't work.  In that case, I'd connect [lastWindowClosed](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qapplication.html#lastWindowClosed) (and maybe also set `quitOnLastWindowClosed` to false, depending on your exact needs).  If your app also ends in other ways (buttons, menus, etc) you'll have to connect those too.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is just to display a message you can follow the answer from *Alex Martelli*.

Else if you need some sort of execution based on close, (such as asking the user about *Do you want to save the changes?* kinda thing), then handling the QCloseEvent* will do the trick.

In such case what I will do is that, extend QWidget class and override its

```
void QWidget::closeEvent ( QCloseEvent * event )   [virtual protected]
```

Under the definition of `closeEvent ( QCloseEvent * event )`, I will have my corresponding execution.

Hope it helps..